# Android: Activity not executing onNewIntent() (called from a Service) from the background

Tags: android, service, android-activity, notifications, foreground

This is my first Android program. I have one activity that reads info outloud, a receiver that listens for incoming SMS messages and a service in order to make the app work in the background.

My main activity has a toggle button. When on, it fires up the service which creates a notification to prevent the app from being killed. The user can also click the notification to return to the main activity:

```
package com.rockmanx77777.SMSbyVoice;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

public class SMSService extends Service{

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        createNotification();
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public class MyBinder extends Binder {
        SMSService getService() {
            return SMSService.this;
        }
    }

    private final IBinder binder = new MyBinder();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    private void createNotification(){

        final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 77777;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SMSByVoice.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra("senderNumber", "");
        intent.setAction("com.rockmanx77777.SMSByVoice.PROCESS");
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent, 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        builder.setContentTitle("Sample Title");
        builder.setContentText("Sample Text");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        builder.setContentIntent(pi);

        Notification notification = builder.getNotification();
        notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }
}
```

The service's onReceive is correctly called when there's an incoming SMS. Everything gets executed including `context.startActivity(localSMS);` It is here that I run into problems:

```
package com.rockmanx77777.SMSbyVoice;
import java.util.Set;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;

public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    public SMSReceiver(){
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("MSG", "Receiver's onReceived Called");
        if(intent.getAction() == "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"){
            //Get the SMS message passed in
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
            String senderNumber = "";
            String body = "";
            if (bundle != null){
                //Retrieve the SMS message received
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
                for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);  
                    body = msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();    
                }
                senderNumber = msgs[0].getOriginatingAddress();

                Intent localSMS = new Intent(context, SMSByVoice.class);
                localSMS.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                localSMS.setAction("rockmanx77777.SMSByVoice.RETURN");
                localSMS.putExtra("senderNumber", senderNumber);
                localSMS.putExtra("body", body);
                Log.d("MSG", "Starting activity from Receiver");
                context.startActivity(localSMS);
            }
        }
        else{
            Log.d("MSG", "intent.getAction() != android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        }
    }
}
```

If the activity is running in the foreground, everything works great. If the activity is running in the background (service and notification created), then `context.startActivity(localSMS);` will execute upon SMS arrival, but the activity's `onNewIntent()` method will not be called nor will the activity be brought to the foreground.

If I manually click the notification sometime after the execution of `context.startActivity(localSMS);` then the activity will come to the foreground (as expected) and now execute `onNewIntent()`.

What I want to happen is that if the activity is running in the background (service and notification created), then upon SMS arrival, my receiver will bring the activity to the foreground (via `startActivity(localSMS);`), and the upon this, the activity will call its `onNewIntent()` method.

I don't know what's wrong. I think the service and receiver are conflicting with each other, but I could be completely off. Sorry it's so long. I can usually find answer to my problems here, but for this issue I've had no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was missing. I did not have a receiver in my service: My service class was changed to this:

```
public class SMSService extends Service{

    SMSReceiver receiver = new SMSReceiver();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d("MSG", "SMSService OnCreate Started");

        createNotification();
        this.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"));
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("MSG", "SMSService OnCreate Ended");
    }

    public class MyBinder extends Binder {...
```